# What does the term "svirfnebli" mean, and how is it different to "svirfneblin"?

Tags: lore, forgotten-realms, gnomes

A recent answer to a question has led me to obtain an e-book for *The Dark Elf Trilogy* by R. A. Salvatore. The section I am reading uses the word "svirfnebli" as well as "svirfneblin". However, I am unsure if it is a printing issue (or possibly a scanning issue) or an actual word, and I can't really tell why is it different from "svirfneblin".

Examples:

> When the **svirfneblin** guards ushered him in

> Scores of **svirfnebli** rushed about their posts

Both seem to be referring to multiple deep gnomes, so I am unsure, but this is the first time I have read the word "svirfnebli", and it is used multiple times in the short part of the book I have read so far. Does anyone know what it means and how it should be used?

If possible, I would like to know if the use of the words has changed through the editions. (Maybe in 3rd edition, they both had a use, and it was simplified for more recent editions?)

Comment: ...Only loosely related: [How do you pronounce “svirfneblin”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50746/33569)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Svirfnebli is the plural noun / adjective for Svirfneblin

Let's switch your examples with Humans:

> When the human guards ushered him in

> Scores of humans rushed about their posts

That should make things more clear. It is confusing, the words are very similar, **but "svirfnebli" is to "svirfneblin" what "elves"/"elven" is to "elf"**. As [fectin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/25662/fectin) pointed out, that is the historic use when the race was first created in [Shrine of the Kuo Toa](https://archive.org/details/tsr09020d2shrineofthekuotoa/page/n5/mode/2up).

---

That being said, as [V2Blast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/33569/v2blast) mentioned, 5th Edition does not mention **svirfnebli** anywhere. In fact, a somewhat deep google search shows few results for that word. We can find [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mines_of_Bloodstone) [user-made](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Blingdenstone#cite_note-campaign3rd-7) [articles](https://www.carrionfields.net/help/race/svirfnebli.php)

> while the svirfnebli fight the duergar

> led a small force of svirfnibli

> The Svirfnebli, also known as deep gnomes

But it seems to either be old content or user-made one. The author in your book distinguishes both words, as do some other works across the Web, but **the more modern and up-to-date use is to use "Svirfneblin" for both singular and plural**, similar to how "Duergar" is used.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but your use of the human example clarifies it perfectly! Thank you.